# How do i make a roblox script start as soon as a player joins the game?

Tags: computer-science, game-engine, startup, roblox, solution

```
local Theme = workspace.CrucibleMusic1
local FlashEffect = script.Parent.FlashEffect
local Camera = workspace.Camera
local ScreenZoomAmount = 0.025 -- How much screen zoom when music is playing
local FlashAmount = 0.75 -- How much screen flash when music is playing
local ScreenAngelsAmount = 0.003 -- How much screen angles change when music is playing
local StandardFieldOfView = 70 -- Standard FieldOfView on roblox better set it to 70

game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    Camera.FieldOfView = StandardFieldOfView - Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenZoomAmount
    FlashEffect.BackgroundTransparency = 1 - Theme.PlaybackLoudness * FlashAmount
    Camera.CFrame = workspace.Camera.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, 
        0, math.rad(math.random(- Theme.PlaybackLoudness,
            Theme.PlaybackLoudness) * ScreenAngelsAmount)) + Vector3.new(
        math.rad(math.random( - Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount,
            Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount) * ScreenAngelsAmount ), 
        math.rad(math.random( - Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount,
            Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount) * ScreenAngelsAmount ), 
        math.rad(math.random( - Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount,
            Theme.PlaybackLoudness * ScreenAngelsAmount) * ScreenAngelsAmount )
    )     
end)
```

How do i make this instantly start when i join?
Im trying to figure out how to make this instantly start when a player joins the game,
But i cant figure out how to do that.
I tried putting it in ServerScriptService but it wouldnt run, Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to help, link your Roblox user in the comments and ill add you to a collaboration group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is put in StarterPlayerScripts or something similar, the script is replicated and is already running on startup. ServerScriptService is for *server scripts*. They run on the server, not the client.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and see if it works.